# How to call a javascript function from android fragment?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, requirejs

I have a webview in a fragment and have my own Bridgecallback services.

I have a javascript file ***TriggerEventsService.js***

```
define(function(require){

    var Service = require('BridgeService');
    var TriggerEventsService = new Service({
        name: "TriggerEventsService",
        timeout : 3000
    });

    //Public API
    TriggerEventsService.postHibernate = function(){
        this.execute("postHibernate", {"event" : "App becoming inactive"}, function(){}, function(){});
    };
```

In my HTML file ***index.html***

```
  function postEventHibernate(){
            require(['TriggerEventsService'], function(ui){
                ui.postHibernate();
            });
        }
```

Can I call this function directly from native android methods ?

In **iOS** I have done this:

```
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"require(['TriggerEventsService'],
 function(ui){ui.postHibernate();});"];
             [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];
```

and ***It works fine*** !I know a way to do it in iOS , figuring anyone can help me out if android has any direct method ?

I have seen other Answers but was not sure how to call the my TriggerEventsService.js - *webview.loadUrl*("**WHAT EXACTLY SHOULD I CALL HERE ?**");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a JavaScript function from java code android native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814843/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-java-code-android-native)

Comment: @LunarWatcher I have seen other answers but was not able to resolve my issue. Can you help me out in this method
 webview.loadUrl(" WHAT Should I call here exactly");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen other Answers but was not sure how to call the my TriggerEventsService.js - webview.loadUrl("WHAT EXACTLY SHOULD I CALL HERE ?");

Assuming that `postEventHibernate()` is a global JavaScript function, this would be:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:postEventHibernate();");
```

FWIW, this is covered in [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), though most of this specific material is in [the preview edition of my advanced `WebView` chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/advanced-uses-of-webview).

Comment: Ahhh I was trying `webview.loadUrl("javascript:postEventHibernate()");` just a semi column away from 8 hours!!  Thanks A lot ! 
**Resolved by:-**      
       `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:postEventHibernate();");
            }
        });`